# element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does it said that `element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`?  I really don't know what to do.

Here is my JS:

```js
const elementsFadeIn = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-in");
window.addEventListener("scroll", fadeIn);
function fadeIn() {
  for (i in elementsFadeIn) {
    let element = elementsFadeIn[i];
    let viewElement = element.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 20;
    if (viewElement < 0) {
        element.classList.add("view-element");
    } 
    else {
        element.classList.remove("view-element");
    }
  }
}
```

and my css code:

```css
.fade-in {
   transform: translateY(50px) translateZ(0);
   transition-delay: 0.7s;
   transition: 1s;
   opacity: 0;
}
     
.view-element{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg) translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you share error message you are getting?

Comment: @Larcis It is in the title `element.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: @CcmU no, `i` means index

Comment: @skara9 thanks for the observation, I was confusing it with `for...of`
Is there any chance that the error is still occurring using something like a `forEach` or a `for...of`?

Comment: @takendarkkk I meant the console output, which would be way more helpful than the title. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You called `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` on a *NodeList* and not on the *DOM element*.

Solution: Access the element at index '0' of the NodeList, getting the DOM element. Remember you are using `querySelectorAll` so your code should be:

```js
let viewElement = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that that the `for ... in ...` loop loops over all `enumerable` properties of an object. The `NodeList` that your `querySelectorAll` returns has numeric keys for each contained element **BUT** also contains the properties `item`, `keys`, `values`, `entries`, `forEach`, and `length`.

But these additional properties are not HTMLElements, hence, they don't have the method `getBoundingClientRect`.

See yourself:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (const item in items) {
  console.log('item: ', item);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Instead you want to use the `for ... of ...` loop.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (const item of items) {
  console.log('item: ', item);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function fadeIn() {
    const elementsToFade = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-in");
    elementsToFade.forEach(element => {
        let viewElement = element.getBoundingClientRect().top - window.innerHeight + 20;
        if (viewElement < 0) {
            element.classList.add("view-element");
        } 
        else {
            element.classList.remove("view-element");
        }
    })
}
```